# Hiding li tag in jquery

Tags: jquery

i bulid a drop down menu using li and ul html tag but now i want to hide some menu depends on user level

CODE:

```
<li id="20"><a href="#">File Generation<br /></a>
                        <ul class="subload"> 
                            <li id="21" ><a href="#">Generate Files<br/></a></li>
                            <li id="22" ><a href="#">Reprocess<br/></a></li>
                            <li id="23" ><a href="#">File Regenerate<br/></a></li>
                            <li id="24" ><a href="#">File Status<br/></a></li>
                        </ul></li>
```

I tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("li #20").hide();

                $("body").on({
                    ajaxStart: function() {
                        $(this).addClass("loading");
                    },
                    ajaxStop: function() {
                        $(this).removeClass("loading");
                    }
                });

                var theForm = $("form[name=MenuBean]");
                var params = theForm.serialize();
                var actionURL = theForm.attr("action");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: actionURL + "?name='Anand'",
                    data: params,
                    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                        alert("Success : " + data);
                        var tmp = data.split("|");
                        for (i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
                            $("li #"+tmp[i]).show();
                        }
                        if (data == "success") {
                        } else {
                            $("#ajaxresult").show().html(data).fadeIn(1000);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, data) {
                        alert("Error : " + data);
                    }
                });
                //event.preventDefault();
            });
```

but its not working properly..

Answer (score 2):

Remove the spaces in your selectors.  `<li id="20">` would be selected with `$("li#20")`, not `$("li #20")`.

`$("li #20")` is looking for an element with an ID of 20 *inside* an li.

Realistically though, you don't need `li` in the selector if you're using an ID, as there should only be 1 element with that ID.

Also, CSS doesn't like IDs that begin with numbers, so you won't be able to reference any of these elements by ID in a stylesheet.  If that's an issue then you should change them to something more descriptive.

Comment: *"Also, some browsers don't like IDs that begin with numbers..."* The don't care about the `id`, but the `id` **selector**. CSS doesn't allow an `id` selector to start with a digit. Also note that there's basically no point to `li#20` (as opposed to just `#20`), unless it's important to ignore the selector if the element with that `id` isn't an `li`.

Comment: Ahh - thanks for the correction.  I knew it had been an issue for me in the past, and I never do it since then.  I'll amend the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector `$("li #"+tmp[i]).show();` is wrong. Your selector is looking for an element with id `x` which is a decedent of a `li` element.

Since you have the element id there is no need to use element selector and id selector.

it should be

```
$("#"+tmp[i]).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove space:

**Change from:**

```
$("li #"+tmp[i]).show();
```

**TO**

```
$("li#"+tmp[i]).show();
```